# How do I have the php linter ignore a line in vscode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, linter

I have a php file with an line that goes like this:

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

The issue is, that this file is installed by Composer, so it does not currently exist. Is there a way to have VSCode ignore this line?

Comment: You can't just run `composer install` to make it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the php-intellisense linter, just try adding the // @php-ignore setting before the line you want to ignore :

```
    // @php-ignore  
    line of code // that you want the linter to ignore
    another line // but this line is not ignored.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Do you think php-intellisense linter is not supporting it anymore?

Comment: Just so you are aware there are two php intelligent extensions available in vs code, namely IntelliSense and Intellifence (phence ??). only keep intelliSense and then @php-ignore should work as shown in above answer.